# Hadoop on AWS gives "java.net.ConnectException Connect refused"

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I set up Hadoop on AWS few days ago, and run a wordcount test. But the task didn't make any progress in 40 mins. Any task including the task yarn uploaded didn't work either. I have 1 Namenode (Master) and 2 Datanode (Slaves).

I look up the log file, first the log of resourcemanager shows that:

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Failed to connect to server: Slave2/172.31.25.60:38729:   And Failed to connect to server: Slave1/balabalablabla
```

I also noticed this error in the log:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Then I download the log of Datanode where the task was undertaked, after read the log I guess the Datanode2 has finished the task but it cannot link to Namenode at that time.

Here is the log file: yarn-ubuntu-resourcemanager-ambari.master.com :
https://github.com/MasterMiror/Hadoop/blob/master/yarn-ubuntu-resourcemanager-ambari.master.com.log (14.6mb just ignore another part of the log I forgot to clean it, read the latest part is ok)

Datanode2's log (the wordcount task ran on it):
[mapreducetask's log](https://github.com/MasterMiror/Hadoop/tree/master/mplog/application_1535702300571_0030) (maybe you think there should be 3 files in each directory but 3 of the files are 0 kb so they weren't uploaded to github)

Here is my configuration file

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
  <value>Master:50090</value>
 </property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoopdata/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoopdata/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://Master/</value>
</property>
</configuration>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>Master</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The same things happened on Slave1 ,also report : Failed to connected to the server: Slave1

Comment: Any reason not to use EMR?

Comment: Just wanna try to set up Hadoop by my self , but not expect it's so hard for me now.

Comment: If you don't understand VPC networking, then yes AWS is hard, and in AWS you should really be using CloudFormation or Terraform because there is very little reason to do it yourself from scratch. Especially in a production environment

Comment: I agree that CloudFormation is a great product, but not for setting up Hadoop. Of course this can be done, but if you are trying to learn how to configure Hadoop and trying to learn CloudFormation, most people would give up long before getting anywhere. Learn the manual steps in setting up Hadoop first, then learn the DevOps tools later. I will bet after learning how to setup Hadoop manually, EMR will look very nice in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to fix. When a HADOOP process can create a new file in HDFS but the file has a 0 length, this usually means that the process can talk to the NameNode (which creates the file) but when the HDFS protocol redirects the process to the DataNode (which stores the data) it fails.

In AWS this usually means that your security group is blocking Master <-> Slave and Slave <-> Slave communication. Create a new security group, enable all ports for all protocols with the source CIDR being the VPC private network (something like 10.0.0.0/16) and assign this security group to each node in your cluster. This security group will allow each node to talk to each other. Make sure that you do not have any DENY rules in other security groups attached to the same cluster that would block node <-> node communication.

Setting up Hadoop as a small cluster is very easy to do. Keep at it until you succeed. This process will help you understand how all the parts go together and most importantly you will be much more comfortable with the Hadoop configuration files. However, I recommend starting with a single node cluster first, then create a real cluster as the next step.

Comment: Thanks ! That's the first time I use AWS so I'm not familiar with those things.

Comment: But after a few days struggle, I found a wired thing that the result has been made, but when I opened ip:8080 I found that the progress was still ZERO , but the result of my task was generated.

Comment: My teacher told me no need to pay attention to this, because the UI of Hadoop is not precise sometimes. I still wonder why my peer's test clusters works well and so as the UI ,and my clusters are ok but the UI is still not working correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry in the second comment, the word "wired ", should be "weird". I'm not very good at English    : b